# Alerts are not kicking in the alertmanger UI despite they're in firing state and I'm not getting notified on my email cleint i.e., outlook

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

[Image of alerts that are in firing state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ee0M.png)

[Image of alerts not kicking in the alert manager UI despite they are firing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGQ1M.png)

Below is my configuration file for alermanager.yml, How can I notified through outlook when metrics are in fired state

```yaml
route:
  receiver: 'Mail Alert'
  group_by: [ 'critical' ]
  repeat_interval: 30s
  group_wait: 15s
  group_interval: 15s

receivers:
  - name: 'Mail Alert'
    email_configs:
      - smarthost: 'smtp.office365.com:587'
        auth_username: 'mars@xilinx.com'
        auth_password: 'secret'
        from: 'mars@xilinx.com'
        to: pluto@amd.com
        headers:
          subject: 'Prometheus Mail Alerts'
```

Below is the prometheus.yml configuration file

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - scheme: http
      static_configs:
        - targets: ['localhost:9093']

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
   - "prometheus.rules.yml"
   - "alerting.rules.yml"
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'prometheus_master'
    file_sd_configs:
    - files: ['targets/*.yml']
      refresh_interval: 30s
```

Comment: Please doc check the attached images as well. Thanks

Comment: Have you configured your prometheus to send alerts to the alertmanager? https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#alertmanager_config

Comment: Is alertmanager actually reachable from prometheus (in docker localhost is not what you think it is)? You can rather easily check this by adding `localhost:9093` into your targets.

Comment: @markalex I'm not running my setup on containers. As you said I added the the localhost as target as well, it's not working either. Please, could you assist me on this. Apart from this I'm not able to get notified on outlook as well. Thanks.