# I'm not getting notified on my email client i.e., outlook despite they're in firing state

Tags: outlook, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Below is the configuration file for alertmanager to send emails when threshold is breached. In my case the alerts are firing but I'm not getting notified on my client outlook in my case. What should I do to get notified.

alertmanager.yml

```
global:
  smtp_smarthost: 'smtp.office365.com:587'
  smtp_from: 'mars@xilinx.com'
  smtp_auth_username: 'mars@xilinx.com'
  smtp_auth_password: 'secret'

route:
  repeat_interval: 1m
  receiver: team-X-mails
receivers:
- name: 'team-X-mails'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'pluto@xilinx.com'
```

prometheus.yml

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - scheme: http
      static_configs:
        - targets: ['localhost:9093']

rule_files:
   - "prometheus.rules.yml"
   - "alerting.rules.yml"

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'


    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'prometheus_master'
    file_sd_configs:
    - files: ['targets/*.yml']
      refresh_interval: 30s
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alerts are not kicking in the alertmanger UI despite they're in firing state and I'm not getting notified on my email cleint i.e., outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78225732/alerts-are-not-kicking-in-the-alertmanger-ui-despite-theyre-in-firing-state-and)